# How can I declare a move constructor of a wrapper type X<T> noexcept depending on is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, noexcept

Assume I have a wrapper type

```
template <typename T>
struct X {/*..*/};
```

and I cannot just `X(X&&) = default` because I have to do non-trivial stuff there.

However, I want it to be `noexcept` but only in case that `T(T&&)` is `noexcept`. This can be tested with `::std::is_nothrow_move_constructible`.

**I'm at a loss how to conditionally enable one version of the constructor or the other depending on a `constexpr`.** I suppose there could be a way to use SFINAE, but I don't see how to apply it to ctors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `noexcept` specifier accepts any boolean constant expression, so you can but your type trait check in there directly:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {
    X(X&&) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) {}
};
```

Comment: Ooooookay, that was easy. Cheers. (I'll accept in an hour)

Comment: I'm using this for the following, just just in case anyone wonders ...
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147999/7189